# Crear una matriz dinamica a partir de datos de otras funciones C++

Tags: c++

Buenas noches. Estoy dándole vueltas a la biblioteca vector y una de las utilidades que le veo que es estupenda es que puedes crear un vector que es una variable

Ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
int a=5;
vector<double> vec(a,0);
}
```

Que seria equivalente a hacer:

```
vec[a];
```

Sentencia esta prohibida en C++.

Mi duda es que no encuentro una idea similar para extender este concepto a matrices como este ejemplo

```
int main()
{
int a=3;
int b=4;
int resultado;
resultado=suma(a,b);

//Crear una matriz a partir de estos resultados tipo m[resultado][a];
}
int suma(int a, int b)
{
return(a+b);
}
```

Se que podria usar "new" pero la duda es si existe otra posibilidad del mismo estilo que "vector". He mirado en CPPreference pero no he encontrado lo que busco.

Saludos.

**EDITO:**

Despues de esta pregunta tengo otra totalmente diferente:

Imaginad que estoy ejecutando una funcion y llego un momento en el que obtengo una serie de arrays dinamicos y quiero retornar uno de ellos. Ejemplo:

```
[...]
a=[1,1]
b=[2,2]
[...]
resultadovec=[1,1,2,2]
resultadomat=[1,1;2,2]
```

¿Puedo pasar este resultado a la funcion principal? Hay que tener en cuenta que las dimensiones y los valores de este array (vectores y matrices) los he obtenido en esta función después de varios cálculos. Yo pienso que no se puede hacer directamente pero me gustaria confirmarlo. La idea si finalmente no se puede es devolver primero el tamaño del vector y matriz que pueda generar, crear ese vector y matriz(de aqui viene la duda anterior) y luego ejecutar de nuevo la funcion (su segunda parte) para que me retorne valores numericos.

Answer (score 1):

Para crear matrices, no necesitas nada mas que un `std::vector< >`. No es necesario complicarse mas.

Los *humanos*, mentalmente, pensamos en una matriz de `4 * 4`como algo así:

> A | A | A | A
>    B | B | B | B
>    C | C | C | C
>    D | D | D | D

**Sin embargo**, esa organización **no es** la que utiliza internamente un ordenador. Esa misma matriz, en memória, se organiza así:

> A | A | A | A | B | B | B | B | C | C | C | C | D | D | D | D

En otras palabras: para el ordenador, una matriz de `4 * 4` es **exactamente lo mismo** que un vector de 16 elementos.

Por lo tanto, para acceder al último elemento de la matriz, podríamos hacer

```
matriz[3][3] = XX
```

o esto, que es lo mismo:

```
vector[15] = XX
```

Esto es extensible a **cualquier número de dimensiones**; da igual que sea de `4 * 4`, o de `3 * 3 * 3`, o de `4 * 6 * 3 * 5`, o cualquier otra combinación.

El único *inconveniente* es que se pierde algo de claridad, debido a que los índices empiezan en 0 y no en 1, pero es cuestión de acostumbrarse.

En lo referente a tu segunda pregunta, la respuesta es igual de sencilla: si quieres devolver un *arreglo* local a tu función, **no puedes**.

Los *arreglos* son en realidad *punteros*; **si puedes** devolver un puntero, **pero** al ser una variable local a tu función, el puntero que devuelves deja de tener sentido en cuanto ejecutes el `return XX;`. Se convierte en una especie de *puntero fantasma*, que apunta a una dirección válidad (las direcciones de memória no cambian), pero el contenido ... pasa a ser *indefinido*; tu contenido original puede permanecer allí ... o puede no estar. O, lo que es peor, puede continuar allí y desaparecer en cualquier momento.

Comment: Bueno sobre la primera parte necesitaria que fuese una matriz puesto que en las sucesivas etapas del programa (ya hechas) es lo que usa. Sobre la segunda parte al final lo que he hecho es devolver el tamaño, crear los vectores y matrices dinamicas y despues llamar a las demas funciones